# When i create new project in android?

Tags: android

When i create new project in android, i found each and every time error sign on project name just like picture, that could not run? So is that any solution to remove this error?
[image: error when creating new project]

[image]
default.properties file seems like this, which is message from error log.

Comment: what does the error say? Or is it just a red x? are you using eclipse?

Comment: I found cross red sign on my new created project , for examples just like picture Helloworld, that it.

Comment: Open the Problems and the Error View from Windows / Short View menu. Maybe, you will get an error message what is wrong. If there is an error show for us.

Comment: yeah i got it.....That message is..............                                                  Error
Mon Aug 08 21:50:25 PDT 2011
Failed to load properties file for project 'Helloworld'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going to Project->Clean... in the menu? This sometimes will help. Also try unchecking Project->Build Automatically and then right click on your project and run as Android.

Edit: You may also have to delete your debug.keystore file. This file should be located in your home directory. Then try clean and build from eclipse and the file should then get recreated.

Comment: @kirean, yes I am already try this many time but could not solved my problem, now another picture added my question look that picture may be some idea you can give me.

Comment: i could not find debug.keystore file, please show up which folder  it is located.

Comment: Windows Vista: C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: @Kieran let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2235/discussion-between-kshetri-horrorgoogle-and-kieran)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar proble. Restarting eclipse might resolve it.

Comment: Still same problem after restarting eclipse.but second picture problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try to fix your properties.

**Right-click the project -> Android Tools -> Fix project properties**

Comment: Interesting. Does this happen when you create a new project from scratch?